# Get div that has onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I have many divs like this:

```
<div id="one" onclick="test('important data one')">ONE</div>
<div id="two" onclick="test('important data two')">TWO</div>
```

And i have a jquery function like this:

```
function test(data){
  //do important stuff with data
}
```

And in that function i need to get the id of the div that was clicked. $(this) doesn't work. I could pass it on as a variable but i don't want to change the html (a lot of it). Can the div be accessed in the function without changing html?

Comment: Adding `this` to each onclick is going to be the easiest option.

Comment: Not sure about this, but, as you are in the onclick="" scope, isn't there an e or event variable? Might have a look there, if so, it should contain the event target. (the div)

Comment: @Johan not in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for Firefox support:

```
<div id="one" onclick="test('important data one',this)">ONE</div>
```

Just send this as a parameter as above.

```
function test(data,el) {
    //do important stuff with data
    alert(el.id);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kJFhP/3/

Comment: Wont work in ff, and in `if (!event) {
        event = window.event;     }`, `event` can only be `window.event`.

Comment: @user1985273 currently testing

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your functions to pass `this` as an argument?

```
<div id="one" onclick="test('important data one', this)">ONE</div>
<div id="two" onclick="test('important data two', this)">TWO</div>
```

And then use that in your function:

```
function test(data, clickedElement){
  //do important stuff with data and the clicked element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `click` handler with jQuery to make it work as you expect:

```
$('#one').click(function() {
  // here you can use $(this)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either add the event parameter to get the event target:

**Event**

```
function test(data, e) {
    // do important stuff with data
    var evt=e||window.event;
    var el=evt.target||evt.srcElement;
    var id=el.id; // id of the clicked div
}
```

which will need these calls:

```
<div id="one" onclick="test('important data one', event)">ONE</div>
<div id="two" onclick="test('important data two', event)">TWO</div>
```

Or, if you think you won't need anything else than this specific element, you may pass it directly like this:

**Element**

```
function test(data, element) {
    // do important stuff with data
    var id=element.id;
}
```

which will need these calls:

```
<div id="one" onclick="test('important data one', this)">ONE</div>
<div id="two" onclick="test('important data two', this)">TWO</div>
```

---

The difference is that in the first case, you can eventually get more information about the event that just been handled. In the second case, you can only get information concerning the element that fired the event (more efficient if you think you won't ever need more information about the event).

Answer (score 0):

I would set your click handlers in the javascript, and not in the html. It is best practice to keep everything separated, and it makes thing a lot easier to maintain. Your case would look something like this if i had to write it:

HTML

```
<div id="one" class='test' data-test='important data one'>ONE</div>
<div id="two" class='test' data-test='important data two'>TWO</div>
```

jQuery

```
    // your function
    function test($div){
      alert('my id is [' + $div.attr('id') + '] and my data is [' + $div.attr('data') . ']'); 
    }

    // when the dom is ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // set the click handlers
        $('.test').click(function() {
           // call your function, with the trigger (as a jQuery object) as parameter        
           test($(this));
        });
    });
```

I have set up a little example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9fwjQ/

I think this should explain itself, but feel free to ask if you need any further help.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to attach data that way, it can be mistaken for html5 data storage; Moreover, your code could be far simplier.

Comment: @Pawel_W the name could perhaps be better, so i updates my answers, though I don't think it is a big issue. Is this not what the data- attribute is for? http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/ Do feel free to elaborate on your 'far simpler' solution. This is a place to post answers after all, and not just comments...